# chrome.runtime.OnMessage.addListener returns duplicate messages

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I am building a simple page-scraping chrome extension to get a page's title and the contents of a shopping cart. I am getting the shopping cart contents twice but not the tittle page. The `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()` function is returning the same message twice to `popup.html` and getting a duplicate of the shopping cart's content and no page title. I have tried to construct the `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`in different ways, to no avail. Please advise on where I went wrong or suggest a better approach?

**manifest.json**

*(permissions are allowed on all urls but I'm currently testing the extension on the checkout page of an ecommerce website)*

```
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Webscraper Extension",
    "description": "Webscraper extension for Chrome",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
```

**poppup.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
         <title>Webscraping Extension</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
         <h3>Checkout</h1>
         <p id='pagetitle'>This should change to the scraped title!</p>
         <div id='cart'>Cart here!</div>
         <button id="checkout" class "button">Checkout</button>
   </body>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </html>
```

**popup.js**

```
// Inject the payload.js script into the current tab after the popout has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });;
});

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').textContent = message;
    document.getElementById('cart').textContent = message;
});
```

**payload.js**

```
// send the page title as a chrome message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.title);
//send the cart as chrome message
var result = "";
var cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName("item-list");
for (var i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
    result += cartItems[i].textContent;
 }
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result);
```

Comment: Remove `background` section from manifest.json and `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().` from popup.js.

Comment: The `background` section is where `popup.js` is declared. In which section should I declare it?

Comment: No, the popup is already declared in browser_action.

Comment: Yes indeed, my bad. I have removed both `background` and `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().`, I am still getting a duplicate of the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result)` message.

Comment: 1) Don't forget to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page 2) Use devtools to inspect the value of `result`, maybe it's incorrect. 3) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I have reloaded the extension after saving the changes, and still get the duplicates. On inspection, `result` returns the scraped cart from `items-list` in the webpage as intended, in `<div id='cart'>Cart here!</div>` but  `document.title` is not displayed in its intended place, `<p id='pagetitle'>This should change to the scraped title!</p>`, instead the  same cart contents are displayed as in `<div id='cart'>Cart here!</div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only one message listener that overwrites the textContent of *both* `pagetitle` and `cart` with whatever message it receives. Therefore, both are overwritten with `result`, which is the latest message received.

Try discriminating the messages with something like:

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message.title) document.getElementById('pagetitle').textContent = message.title;
    if (message.cart) document.getElementById('cart').textContent = message.cart;
});
```

**payload.js**

```
// send the page title as a chrome message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({title:document.title});
//send the cart as chrome message
var result = "";
var cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName("item-list");
for (var i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
    result += cartItems[i].textContent;
 }
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({cart:result});
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution and I'm  getting `no title` in place of the title and the cart contents as intended in `({cart:result})`.

Comment: @Gokuh Check the edit I've made to the code.

Comment: It worked! Both scraped title and cart contents are showing in the popup. Thank you for your help!